# Trouble installing boost on Leopard using macports

Tags: port, osx-leopard, mac-osx

Building boost with macports falls causes a cc1plus process to run forever.  Anyone know anything about this?  (BTW, port is version 1.710 and I'm running OS X 10.5.6 with kernel 9.6.0)

```
$ port install boost
--->  Fetching boost
--->  Attempting to fetch boost_1_38_0.tar.bz2 from http://superb-east.dl.sourceforge.net/boost
--->  Verifying checksum(s) for boost
--->  Extracting boost
--->  Applying patches to boost
--->  Configuring boost
--->  Building boost
```

Comment: Intel or PPC processor?

Comment: Intel.

Darwin Kernel Version 9.6.0: Mon Nov 24 17:37:00 PST 2008; root:xnu-1228.9.59~1/RELEASE_I386 i386

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried running `sudo port -d install boost` to enable debug messages in hopes of finding out what it's stuck on?

Comment: Just tried that but neither -v or -d (or both) show more output.

Comment: Oh, it's actually "port -d install", not "port install -d".  I'm running it at the moment.

Comment: A lot of files are being compiled; perhaps it just takes a long time.  I'm still monitoring it.

Comment: OK, it finished.  Took half an hour but it finished.  Thanks for the suggestion, I'd consider that the answer ;-)

Comment: Sorry bout the flag in the incorrect position. Bad memory.